# how does bitbake parse task with -c option

Tags: bitbake

When I executed bitbake -c task task execution was successful. I wanted to know how bitbake is parsing task provided with -c option. Can anyone help me with the code flow.

Answer (score 0):

There are various tasks like `do_compile`, `do_configure`, `do_rootfs` and so on that the bitbake does when building a given recipe. Check [here](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-tasks) for the list of tasks.

When we want to perform only a specific task of our choice, we need the `-c <task>` switch for bitbake. Here is an example of such context.

The kernel under Yocto is managed by the recipe `sources/meta-fsl-arm/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_4.9.11.bb` file (in my case). I've added some modules that I've created on my own. In this case, though you've modified the kernel (linux-imx) and the time stamps are updated, the bitbake relies on `sstate-cache` information for verifying if a given recipe is worked on or not.

However, you have a change in the recipe file so, it needs to be compiled again. In such case, you opt for the command `bitbake -c compile linux-imx -f`, with which we are instructing the bitbake tool to "compile" the recipe `linux-imx` forcefully using `-f`. You can perform any other task in the same way like `-c menuconfig` for configuration menu, `-c distrodata` for data about the distribution, `-c checkpkg` for checking the list of packages and so on.

For better understanding, go through the latest version of [Yocto Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html).